# How can I run FxCop on an entire solution in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, fxcop

There must be  simple way, I do not want to run Code Analysis separately on each project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the dumb response before..Here's what you REALLY do :)

Set each project to run code analysis on build:

- right-click the project,
- go to the Code Analysis tab
- click "Enable Code Analysis on Build"

When you build the solution, it will run CA on each project

Comment: Where's this Code Analysis tab you're talking about? Is it specific to VSTS? I am using Professional Edition and can't find it... I use a post-build event to run FxCop.

Comment: @Martinho - I'm using Professional also. Right click the project, and choose properties. It should open a view with a series of tabs. That's what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom MsBuild task that does this.

http://ripper234.com/p/msbuild-fxcopsolution-task/